# Can i convert my Road bike to a Fixed Gear bike?

Tags: road-bike, fixed-gear, conversion

I was just wondering if i can convert my aluminum road bike into a fixed gear bike? If so, what is the BEST/SAFEST way to do so?... Reason why is because i have no need for gears due to the fact that i only ride on flat surfaces for short periods of time throughout the day. The dropouts on my bike are perpendicular to the ground by the way... Thanks in advanced! 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want a single-speed with a freewheel or truly fixed?

Comment: Cheapest/simplest/safest way to do it is to get a regular multi-speed rear wheel and appropriate derailer and then only use one speed.  The derailer can be "locked" to the desired speed if you want to completely forego shifters.

Comment: What i want is truly fixed

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The best way to do it is to use a [White Industries ENO Eccentric Hub](http://www.whiteind.com/eno/) (I don't care that I'm giving a product recommendation here because this is the only product that's ever done what it does), the alternative being using a [magic ratio setup.](http://eehouse.org/fixin/fixmeup.php) The other part of it is getting set up with the proper chainline up front.

Comment: Can i use a hub from a BMX bike and just rel-lace it with the spokes from my road bikes rear tire?

Comment: No, BMX uses 110mm frame spacing, and spokes can only be re-used in this manner if they happen to be the right length.

Comment: Note that the Eno Eccentric hub (I added a link to the answer) goes for $190 retail, most likely more than the cost of your bike itself.

Comment: ??? It's got Campy...